# React TestUtils Simulate focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to test focusing on one of my custom React Components.

It returns an `Input` React component with an `onFocus` handler.

Here is my test:

```
let hasCalledFocus = false
const myInput = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <MyInput
        focusHandler={() => {
            console.log('focus')
            hasCalledFocus = true
        }}
        hasFocus={false}
        text=''
    />
)

const input = TestUtils.scryRenderedComponentsWithType(myInput, Input)
expect(hasCalledFocus).to.eql(false)
TestUtils.Simulate.focus(input[0])
expect(hasCalledFocus).to.eql(true)
```

When I make these exact calls on a non-React component, using `const input = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(myInput, 'div')`, everything works as expected. The focusHandler method I pass to the component is called and the test passes. For some reason, I can't get it to focus on my React component.

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be going on here? I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: We may need to see what the `MyInput` component looks like.  Just to double-check that the event is propagating.

Comment: @Davin Tryon It looks like the component should. With all the correct props and everything. Even the focusHandler is there

Comment: @DavinTryon don't think I tagged you correctly before....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I wasn't handling `type` explicitly in my custom `MyInput` component class. I am usually just passing it as a prop when I create `MyInput`, like so: `<MyInput type='text' ... />`, but I had left that out of my test by accident.

So the test couldn't find the component because it didn't know what kind of `Input` type it's supposed to render.